# RSpec testing instance variable to ID with eq explanation

Tags: rspec

In the following spec

```
describe 'PUT update' do
  before :each do
    @contact = Factory(:contact, firstname: "Lawrence", lastname: "Smith")
  end

  context "valid attributes" do
    it "located the requested @contact" do
      put :update, id: @contact, contact: Factory.attributes_for(:contact)
      assigns(:contact).should eq(@contact)      
    end
  end
end
```

what is `assigns(:contact).should eq(@contact)` testing? Is it testing whether or not @contact is equal to the id of @contact...? Why is it `id: @contact` then and not the entire `@contact`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is doing some magic for you here. When you call this line

```
put :update, id: @contact, contact: Factory.attributes_for(:contact)
```

rails automatically finds the `id` of `@contact` and passes that in as the value of the `id` parameter

---

The `assigns(:contact).should eq(@contact)` is checking that the controller method that updates this "contact" is setting an instance variable called `@contact` with the same data as your test contact

---

It might be a bit clearer of you changed some variable names (I renamed `@contact` in your test to `@test_contact`)

```
describe 'PUT update' do
  before :each do
    @test_contact = Factory(:contact, firstname: "Lawrence", lastname: "Smith")
  end

  context "valid attributes" do
    it "located the requested @contact" do
      put :update, id: @test_contact, contact: Factory.attributes_for(:contact)
      assigns(:contact).should eq(@test_contact)      
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you're `@test_contact` example really cleared things up for me. thanks!